# SVO pattern or SVOO pattern?

Tags: indirect-objects

> 1. I wrote him a letter.
> 2. I wrote a letter to him.

The pattern of the first sentence is SVOO. Some grammar books and sites say that the second sentence is also in SVOO  pattern. But some others say it is not SVOO, and the **him** of the second sentence is not an Indirect Object.

Please do not close this as a duplicate question. My questions are different:

> a) If the **him** is not an Indirect Object, what is the  pattern of
> the second sentence?
>
> b) What grammatic function does the PP **to him** do in the sentence?

Comment: Different grammar books use different language to describe the same thing. Is there a particular reason why it *matters* if it's SVOO or not? Does the particular analysis change something relevant?

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, when I talked about  the basic sentence patterns (SV, SVO, SVC, SVOO, SVOC, SVOA), I used the first sentence as an example of SVOO, then  someone raised a question using the second sentence, *isn't that an SVOO sentence?*

Comment: I understand the question, but I still don't understand why it's necessary to know if it fits that pattern or not. As I said, it depends on who you ask. So, depending on that, the answer is either yes or no. What I was trying to clarify was what *purpose* is solved by its classification. Does getting a particular answer solve something or prevent something from being solved?

Comment: @JasonBassford If it comes as a question in a test, what will be the answer?

Comment: There is no absolute answer. You would have to guess what grammar source the maker or makers of the test follow. If it requires a yes or no answer, and that information is not provided, either in the test or as part of the course material that went before, then it's a poor test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is a dispute about how best to analyse the grammar of the second sentence.

> 1. I wrote **him a letter**.

I think everyone agrees that in the first sentence, "him" is an indirect object, and "a letter" is the direct object.

> 2. I wrote **a letter to him**.

Older grammars, including Quirk et al., regard "him" as an indirect object.  Quirk et al. describes it as a "prepositional object" consisting of a preposition plus an indirect object.

Huddleston & Pullum regards "to him" as a complement consisting of a prepositional phrase giving more information about the person for whom or to whom the action was done.

References:

- Quirk, Leach & Greenbaum, *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Longman 1985.
- Huddleston & Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, CUP, 2002.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. **Is sentence 2 SVOO?** 'Fowler's Modern English Usage' says, "The person or thing secondarily affected by the action stated by the verb, if expressed by a noun or pronoun alone (i.e. without *to*, *for*, etc.) is called the i.o. "The English dative now having no separate form, the i.o. must be otherwise identified, and this is done by putting it between the verb and the object, and if it is to follow the object, must be replaced by a preposition phrase (Hand that book *to me*; Call a taxi *for me*)".

Comment: Some authorities consider it to be SVOO.  But some newer scholarship suggests that it isn't.  In your quote, Fowler agrees with H&P.