# Use paint in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Sentences like: I painted the door blue. Has a the sentence structure of SVOC.

Now in the following sentence:

I'll paint the stone a ladybird.

Is this sentence also right? I am asking because this sentence also follows the same sentence structure  SVOC.

Or is this wrong because in SVOC the complement must be an adjective and lady bird is not an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound natural. I'd prefer to say "I'll paint the stone *as* a ladybird" (or even "... to look like a ladybird" though given my artistic skills it wouldn't look much like one).

It would make grammatical but not logical sense to interpret "I'll paint the stone a ladybird" to mean that you'll paint a picture of a ladybird and give it to the stone (compare "I'll paint my friend a landscape").

Further reading on the SVOO  structure of your example can be found in the answer to [SVO pattern or SVOO pattern?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/258359/5323)

Comment: Or "I'll paint a ladybird on the stone" (implying 'a picture of a ladybird').

Comment: @KateBunting indeed.  I was thinking of a ladybird-shaped stone, painted all over to resemble a ladybird.  That sort of thing is quite popular with kids round my way and my daughter ropes me in too (but I get the irregular stones and end up painting a tiny pirate island, or turning a dried bean into a penguin)